# Agent/Customer can't find any Email Notification in OTRS?

Tags: mysql, email, imap, pop3, otrs

I have installed OTRS 5.0.12 in liux machine successfully. in Email configuration i have felt some problem.i have set send mail & Postmaster Mail Account successfully. check & set validity in Ticket Notification. all things are ok.
But when i create ticket agent can't find email notification in his inbox??

My Emails are fetched in OTRS. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're an agent and create a ticket assigned to yourself, you will not receive a notification.

If you want to be sure an email was sent, please check the OTRS log file, it should show the outgoing emails.

Comment: i have solved partially. when create ticket then mail goes to external mail address such as gmail, yahoomail but cannot find in the internal mail address, i have set ticket create notification & set the agent name in "send to these agent field" but it cannot work. please help.